# Parse broken HTML Code using Nodejs & Cheerio

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to scrape a pure static html page with tabular data in it using Nodejs & Cheerio. But the problem is that, the page is am trying to scrape doesnt have proper HTML DOM. I mean, there are many opening tags which are not closed. There are other closing tags(`</table>`) which has no openings.

A sample Code (Alert: The Code is close to real sample & html is broken)

```
  <body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" link="#003399" vlink="#003399" alink="#FF8000">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr><td bgcolor="#445BC6">hii</td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" bgcolor="#D9D9E8" width="100%">
                <p class="menu"><b><font color="#000000"><a href="details.php?type=contact&npo_id=18430">Individuals</a></font></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <P>
    <TABLE CELLPADDING=8><TR><TD>&nbsp;</TD><TD>
                <TABLE CELLPADDING=8 STYLE="border-collapse: collapse" BORDER=1 WIDTH=80% ALIGN=cemter>

                    <TR><TD BGCOLOR="D8D8C4" VALIGN=top ALIGN=right><P><B>Data 1</B></TD>
                        <TD><P><B>Data 2</B></TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR><TD BGCOLOR="D8D8C4" VALIGN=top ALIGN=right><P><B>Data 3</B></TD>
                        <TD><P>Data 4</TD>
                    </TR>


                </TABLE>
            </TD></TR></TABLE>            <tr>
    <td width="100%" valign="bottom" colspan="2" align="center">
        <p>
            <a href="#top">another dirty content</a><br>
            <a href="#top"><font color="#000000">table is wrong</font></a></p>
    </td>
</tr></table></div>
```

As one can see there are P tags which are not closing.. At the bottom there is 
     `</table>` & `</div>` tags which are not opening.
So how do i fetch Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4 using cheerio & nodejs ? Any other library will also do which is efficient in parsing such data

EDIT(SOLUTION): The problem is solved. All I did was just converted the html tags to lower-case and it worked fine..Am not sure why lower-case is important but it just worked for cheerio

Comment: Scraping with regexes is not that difficult, especially if the pages all have similar formatting. Here: http://pastebin.com/SRDYBxpX is an example written in python that scrapes piratebay. Regexes have the definite advantage that they ignore any issues with closing and opening tags. and you can use the tags enclosing the data you require to safely delimit what the given regex will capture.

Answer (score 0):

`cheerio` is built around `htmlparser2`, which is supposed to be "forgiving". If it doesn't parse your page, and I know this is against conventional wisdom, I would parse using regular expressions. This is assuming the page structure won't change much, and it's only that one page you are trying to parse.

Also, I noticed a link at the top of your sample HTML, to `individuals.php`. Could the data you are after be there, in a different, more parseable format?

Oh, and respect people's privacy, and sites usage terms, when scraping.